# Getting a no such element exception dont know why

Tags: arrays, java.util.scanner

I need to create two arrays from a file that has 3 columns of data. This is what I have made so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReadFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
 Scanner inFile=null;
 try
 {
   inFile = new Scanner (new File("data.txt"));;
 }
 catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println ("File not found!");
        // Stop program if no file found
        System.exit (0);
    }
 int count=0;
 int[] year = new int[40];
 int[] temperature = new int[40];
 inFile.nextInt();
 while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {


   year[count] = inFile.nextInt();
   temperature[count] = inFile.nextInt();
   inFile.nextInt();
   count++;
}


System.out.println(Arrays.toString(year));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temperature));
}
}
```

The data file looks like this.
    1  1950  11

```
2  1950  22

3  1950  65

4  1950  103

5  1950  99

6  1950  54

7  1950  109

8  1950  85

9  1950  72

10  1950  120

11  1951  26

12  1951  35

13  1951  59

14  1951  110

15  1951 103

16  1951  49

17  1951  99

18  1951  91

19  1951  85

20  1951  117

21  1953  26

22  1953  41

23  1953  69

24  1953  110

25  1953  100

26  1953  72

27  1953  87

28  1953  102

29  1953  95

30  1953  102

31  1954  33

32  1954  46

33  1954  57

34  1954  106

35  1954  119

36  1954  93

37  1954  57

38  1954  89

39  1954  88

40  1954  92
```

The file makes 100% sense to me and sounds like it should work, but im getting this strange exception. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are the numbers 1-40 at the beginning of each line being mistaken as years or temperatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `inFile.hasNextInt()` for every 3 calls to `inFile.nextInt()`. Whereas the last call doesn't have a next integer because you are at the end of the file (after `92` in `40  1954  92` has been read).

You can shift your index by one to get around this i.e.:

```
 int[] year = new int[40];
 int[] temperature = new int[40];
 while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {

   inFile.nextInt(); //the throw away value
   year[count] = inFile.nextInt();
   temperature[count] = inFile.nextInt();
   count++;
}
```

Comment: so sorry Im new to the website